# route in react native

Tags: react-native, react-router

i have applied the route in my program but the output is showing only the background color there is a login and signup form in that but it is not shown there what is the reason behind that

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Login from './pages/Login';
import Signup from './pages/Signup';

export default class Routes extends Component<{}> {
    render(){
        return(
        <Router>
        <Stack key="root">
          <Scene key="Login" component={Login} title="Login" />
          <Scene key="Signup" component={Signup} title="Signup" />
        </Stack>
      </Router>
    )
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you please share the whole code , so that we can easily understand what's the problem. its unclear now actually,

Comment: yes i can but i dont know how to send

Comment: can you please provide me email  then i will send

Comment: you can add your code to https://snack.expo.io/ , so that i can check there and share me the link of the expo snack

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/r1Lt2-vYS

Comment: what  happen did you get it